# PDE continuous dependence on data definition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let us have a linear partial differential equation
$$u_t + Au = f.$$
If I know that
$$|u| \leq C(|u_0| + |f|)$$
then does that mean I know "continuous dependence on initial data"?

Is this common in the literature? Or should I instead write
$$|u-v| \leq C(|u_0-v_0|)$$
for 2 solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/~frey/cours/UdC/ma691/ma691_ch3.pdf , Page 7 (Definition 3.4 and text below) for a Definition. Basically, it means the latter of your proposals, although we need not have a Lipschitz-continuity.